# Periodic Steady State voltage Buck Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, converter, steady-state

What does Periodic Steady state mean with regard to a Buck Converter ? Does it mean the normal operation  ?

Also, From what I read, the net change in the capacitor voltage in the buck converter is 0. Why is it so ? Is it because it becomes constant ?

Comment: Where did you read the statements?

Comment: On a course online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodic steady state does mean normal operation (which obviously isn't a constant output voltage).  The idea is that the dynamics of the converter have settled and all startup transients have settled.

The net change in the capacitor voltage in a buck converter must be zero or else the output voltage would be moving around, which means the circuit wouldn't be working as a DC-DC converter.  So yes, I would say it is because the output DC voltage settles to be a constant (with some ripple).